# Insert columns with constants in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a row of pandas dataframe, i.e.

```
x p y q z
---------
1 4 2 5 3
```

I want to append only some columns ('x','y','z') of it to another dataframe as new columns with names 'a','b','c'.

Before:

```
A B
---
7 8
9 6
8 5
```

After

```
A B a b c
---------
7 8 1 2 3
9 6 1 2 3
8 5 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) by `Series` created by selecting 1. row of `df1`:

```
cols = ['x','y','z']
new_cols = ['a','b','c']
df = df2.assign(**pd.Series(df1[cols].iloc[0].values, index=new_cols))
print (df)

   A  B  a  b  c
0  7  8  1  2  3
1  9  6  1  2  3
2  8  5  1  2  3
```

Comment: How to leave existent df1 and df2 without any changes?

Comment: Now both solutions do it.

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1],'y':[2],'z':[3]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,9,8],'B':[8,6,5]})
print pd.concat([df2,df1],axis=1).fillna(method='ffill').rename(columns={'x':'a','y':'b','z':'c'})

   A  B    a    b    c
0  7  8  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  9  6  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  8  5  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: How to map columns with names x,y,z to a,b,c?